# vscode.commands.executeCommand was not working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing an VS Code extension to help migrating **React.createClass** to **class extends React.Component**. The problem here was, I could not get `vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeFormatDocumentProvider', ...)` to work.

Note that the code below is pure JavaScript, but not TypeScript.

```
function activate(context) {
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('migrate-to-react-es6-class', () => {
        const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor
        const document = editor.document

        try {
            const originalCode = document.getText()
            const modifiedCode = 'do something and return new code'

            if (originalCode === modifiedCode) {
                vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Nothing is to be migrated.')

            } else {
                editor.edit(edit => {
                    const editingRange = document.validateRange(new vscode.Range(0, 0, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER))
                    edit.replace(editingRange, modifiedCode)
                })

                if (document.isUntitled === false) {
                    vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeFormatDocumentProvider', document.uri, { insertSpaces: true, tabSize: 2 })
                }
            }

        } catch (error) {
            vscode.window.showErrorMessage(error.message)
            console.error(error)
        }
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After 3.25 years, you've probably figured this out by now, but for the record, I assume you hung a .then() on the editor.edit() and then moved the executeCommand to within the then(), right?

```
editor.edit(edit => {
    const editingRange = ...
    edit.replace(editingRange, modifiedCode)
}).then(editWorked => {if (editWorked && !document.isUntitled) {
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeFormatDocumentProvider', ...) })
```

Answer (score 0):

You must apply returned edits

```
private async formatDocument(): Promise<void> {
    const docUri = this.textEditor.document.uri;
    const textEdits = (await vscode.commands.executeCommand(
        'vscode.executeFormatDocumentProvider',
        docUri,
    )) as vscode.TextEdit[];
    const edit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
    for (const textEdit of textEdits) {
        edit.replace(docUri, textEdit.range, textEdit.newText);
    }
    await vscode.workspace.applyEdit(edit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it directly in the extension.ts:

```
    commands.registerCommand(constants.commands.formatDocument, async () => {
    const docUri = editor?.document.uri;
    const textEdits: TextEdit[] | undefined = await commands.executeCommand(
      'vscode.executeFormatDocumentProvider',
      docUri
    );
    if (textEdits && docUri) {
      const edit = new WorkspaceEdit();
      for (const textEdit of textEdits) {
        edit.replace(docUri, textEdit.range, textEdit.newText);
      }
      await workspace.applyEdit(edit);
    }
  });
```

`constants.commands.formatDocument` gets the value after parsing my package.json